# Css file is not detected by react+vite Configuration

Tags: css, reactjs, web, tailwind-css, vite

I have created a reactjs project using vite but the css files are not getting detected below my config files and everything.

//Vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

//talwind.config.cjs

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{html,ts,js,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

//package.json

```
{
  "name": "adminpanelv1",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.0.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh": "^1.3.6",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "chart.js": "^4.1.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^12.1.4",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-modal": "^3.16.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.2",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.1",
    "vite-react-css": "^0.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "vite": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

//index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Admin Panel</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
```

Now I am using css but it's not detecting the css file

```
---Folder-Name: Tabs
 --File:- Tabs.jsx (import "./Tabs.css"; or "../Tabs/Tabj.css")
 --Css File:- Tabs.css
```

I dont know what is the reason not to detect css file and searced everywhere still not got the solution. It just says no suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You should write something like

Import '(path)yourcss.css';

above your Application or Main jsx.
Note that css properties will overlap depending on how you call your jsx.